# WP ACF dynamic <iframe> source

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, advanced-custom-fields, vimeo-player

**Hello guys** i am using WordPress with the advanced custom fields plugin. On my site i have a custom link field. The Link changes on every Blog Post.

So i want that the Link in the Iframe changes dynamically.

//with get_field i can load the value of field ‘text_field’ from the current post:

```
$value = get_field( "text_field" );
```

This is my Iframe:

````
> ```<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" id="iframePlayer"
> src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/417538229?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0"
> frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen=""
> allowfullscreen="" data-ready="true"></iframe>```
````

How can change the src of the iframe and integrate the get field function into my Iframe Player?

I thought about document.getElementById(id);?

Thanks a lot :)
Greetings Chris

Comment: Well if it is a custom template and code.. Just use in the `src="<?php echo $value;?>"`?

Comment: Hey mate :) Thanks a lot. That worked out for me. Greetings Chris